# $\Omega(X)$ space of homolomorphic $1$-forms over Riemann surface $X$, $H_a=\{\omega\in\Omega(X):\omega(a)=0\}$. Then $\dim(H_a)=g$ or $g-1$

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry

$X$ is compact closed riemann surface and $\Omega(X)$ space of homolomorphic 1-forms over $X$, $H_a=\{\omega\in\Omega(X):\omega(a)=0\}$. Then $\dim(H_a)$ is either $g$ or $g-1$.

$\textbf{Q1:}$Why $\dim(H_a)$ is either $g$ or $g-1$? I tried riemann roch by considering the following. $\Omega(X)\cong O_{K_X}$ where $K_X$ is any canonical divisor. Then $H_a$ is the subspace s.t. vanishing at $a$ at least once. So $H_a=O(K_X-a)$. However $l(a)=\deg(a)+1-g+l(K_x-a)=2-g+l(K_x-a)$. Then I do not know what is $l(a)$ and $l(K_x-a)$.

Ref: Forster, Riemann Surface on Jacobi Inversion Problem.

Comment: For the second question, it is a fairly standard result that for a genus $g$ Riemann surface, $H_1 (X , Z ) = R^{2g}$ where $R$ is your coefficient ring. The image of a free module on $2g$ generators has at most $2g$ generators.

Comment: @Rellek Do I know it has to be free? Should I say image of free to $C^n$ is free?

Comment: No, the image of a free module is definitely not always free (since else every module would be free, as it is always the quotient of a free modue). In this case, since the authors are referring to free abelian groups, the coefficient ring is $\mathbb{Z}$, which is a PID. Moreover $\Omega ( X)$ is free, whence its dual is free. Thus the image of the map $H_1 (X , Z) \to \big( \Omega (X ) \big)^*$ is a submodule of a finitely generated free module over a PID, hence itself free.

Comment: @Rellek Just a nitpick : $\Omega(X)$ is free as a $\mathbb{C}$-vector space (like every vector space), but not as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module, and it is not finitely generated either. However it is torsion free, so the image of $H_1$ is finitely generated and torsion free, hence free.

Comment: @Roland That's a pretty large oversight of mine. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: $l(K_x-a)$ is what you are looking for. $l(a)\geq 1$ because $\mathcal{O}(a)$ contains the constant functions. We also have $l(a)\leq 2$ because $a$ is a divisor of degree 1. So $l(a)=1$ or $2$ which proves the claim. Actually the case $l(a)=2$ is rather specific : it is only possible when $X=\mathbb{P}^1$.

Comment: @Roland How do I deduce $l(a)\leq 2$ here? Do I use the fact that $\psi+a\geq 0$ implies that $\psi$ can only has a simple pole at $a$? Hence, the function has a pole at $a$. Any meromorphic function with a single pole at $a$ is as good as any other with a poly at $a$ as they are all differ by a constant. Hence $l(a)\leq 2$. How do I get $l(a)=2$ iff $X=P^1$? Thanks.

Comment: @Roland Maybe this is a even dumb question. When does $l(a)=1$ hold? The argument above did not say anything about existence of function with a simple pole at $a$.

Comment: Yes if two functions $f_1,f_2$ have a simple pole at $a$, then there is a linear combination $f$ which has no poles at $a$ (just cancel out the residues). If $a$ is their only pole, then $f$ has no pole, so is constant. It follows that every function in $\mathcal{O}(a)$ is a linear combination of $1$ (constant function) and $f_1$ (any other if it exists). So $l(a)\leq 2$.

Comment: If $l(a)=2$, then any non constant function $f$ in $\mathcal{O}(a)$ defines a degree 1 map $X\to\mathbb{P}^1$ so is an isomorphism $X\simeq\mathbb{P}^1$. (The degree is 1 because it has only one pole and this pole is simple). So for any $X$ which is of genus $g>0$ and any $a\in X$, $l(a)=1$. And if $X$ is of genus $0$, then $l(a)=2$ for any $a$.

Comment: @Roland Rellek Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation.